# Steady-state solution

Tags: boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

> Obtain the steady-state solution of the problem $$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\gamma^2(u-T)=\frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}, \ 0<x<a, \ t>0,$$ $$u(0,t)=T, \ u(a,t)=T, \ 0<t,$$ $$u(x,0)=T_1\frac{x}{a}, \ 0<x<a.$$

Since steady-state doesn't depend on time then we will have: $$\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2}+\gamma^2(v-T)=0, \ 0<x<a,$$ $$v(0)=T, \ v(a)=T, $$

but the solution given is $v(x)=T$ which I don't know how they obtained?

Comment: Are you sure the sign of the linear term, $\gamma^2(u-T)$, is right?  It should be negative to correctly describe radiative loss when the temperature exceeds the ambient temperature $T$.  As you have it, there may well be other steady-state solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the equation should read $\frac{d^2 v}{dx^2} - \gamma^2 (v-T) = 0$.

Use the substitution $V \equiv v - T$. Note that the derivatives of $V$ are that same as that of $v$ because the constant term $T$ drops upon differentiation. The differential equation reduces to

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2 V}{dx^2} - \gamma^2 V & = 0 \\
V(0) = 0, V(a) & = 0
\end{align*}

which has solution $V = A \exp(\gamma x)+ B \exp(-\gamma x)$

We have $V(0) = A + B = 0$ and $V(a) = A \exp(\gamma a) + B \exp(- \gamma a) = 0$, hence $A\left[ \exp(\gamma a) - \exp(-\gamma a) \right] = 0$. Note that $\exp(\gamma a) - \exp(-\gamma a) = 0$ if and only if $\gamma a = 0$ which is not the case and therefore $A = 0$.

We may conclude that $V(x) = 0$ hence $v(x) = T$.

In case the equation really reads $\frac{d^2 v}{dx^2} + \gamma^2 (v-T) = 0$, you get the general solution

\begin{align*}
V(x) = A \cos(\gamma x) + B \sin(\gamma x)
\end{align*}

In this case you will find $v(x) = T$ under the assumption that $\gamma a \neq n \pi$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The problem right before this had it as negative whereas this problem had it as positive but nevertheless I still needed help solving this question too. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am pretty sure it should be $-\gamma^2$ as the temperature exceeding $T$ should result in a outward heat flux. Is $k$ maybe negative ?

Comment: Nope, but it states "Can you think of a physical interpretation of this problem?Note the difference between the partial differential equation in this exercise and in Exercise 1 (which you just did).What happens if γ = π/a?"

Comment: If $\gamma = \pi / a$ then $\gamma a = \pi$ and the solution is not unique anymore. This follows from the fact that $V(0) \implies A = 0$ but $V(a) = B \sin(\gamma a) = 0$ without $B$ being $0$ (because the sine is). B can assume any value which makes the general solution $v(x) = B \sin(\gamma x) + T$ but I don't know what that means physically.